# Swift - Identify word before cursor in textView (with special Characters)

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextview

I have an extension which identify and return the word before the cursor:

```
extension UITextView {

var currentWord : String? {

    let beginning = beginningOfDocument

    if let start = position(from: beginning, offset: selectedRange.location),
        let end = position(from: start, offset: selectedRange.length) {

        let textRange = tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(end, with: .word, inDirection: 1)

        if let textRange = textRange {
            return text(in: textRange)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I am using UItextGranularity.word and works fine.

However my issue is this:

If at the beginning of the word i have an @ it won't be returned.
so if i have @jon the currentword will be jon.
Is there a way to include the @ so to have the complete word with the special Character?

Thank you

Comment: Spent all day to get right where you were at for the exact same problem. Glad we got an answer!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you can do it with `UITextInputTokenizer`. You can try this solution:

```
var currentWord: String? {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\S+$")
    let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: selectedRange.location)
    if let range = regex.firstMatch(in: text, range: textRange)?.range {
        return String(text[Range(range, in: text)!])
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer... i'm new to swift so i'm struggling a bit... i've tried your method but it return always nil...

Comment: Do you have a space at the end of your selected text range?

Comment: no it's an input in the textview. Basically i'm trying to get the last word the user wrote and if he got back with the cursor the last word before the cursor

Comment: By "got back with the cursor" do you mean moving the position of the cursor or that the user deletes the text?

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should help you, but it's not perfect. The issue is that if the cursor is halfway through a word then it will give you up until that character of the word.

Comment: Which is perfect because i'm using it just to check if that word begins with the "@"... thanks a lot! u saved me a lot of headaches... :)

Comment: No problem. Please mark the question as answered ;)

Comment: this will crash with multi-byte characters like emojis. it should be `return (text as NSString).substring(with: range)`.